# How to have CCC Loss Function in PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch, loss-function

How would one write a custom loss function (in this case for [CCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concordance_correlation_coefficient)) for PyTorch that behaves similar to other losses like `backwards()`?

[image: CCC from Wikipedia]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you use PyTorch operators that are differentiable, your function will be too.

So, using [`torch.mean`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.mean.html), [`torch.var`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.var.html), and [`torch.cov`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cov.html). Isn't that be what your looking for?

```
def CCCLoss(x, y):
    ccc = 2*torch.cov(x, y) / (x.var() + y.var() + (x.mean() - y.mean())**2)
    return ccc
```